# Chrome input text field keyboard lag with multiple dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

Hopefully my title is easy to understand. I have a form that needs to allow for a dynamic number of input field sets. That is, a user can add a new table row containing 5 text fields. I add these rows using jQuery, I take the base row, clone it, blank all text values in the clone, and append it to the table body. Abbreviated code is below:

```
var num    = $('#num').val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
var numAdd = 1; // default, add only 1 new row
if (num.length > 0) {
  var baseRow = $('#base'); // this is a tr tag
  numAdd = parseInt(num);
  if (numAdd >= 1) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= numAdd; i++) {
      var newRow = $(baseRow).clone();
      $(newRow).find('input').val('');
      $('#rows').append(newRow); // this is a tbody tag
    }
  }
}
```

What I've noticed is the more dynamic rows I add to the page, the greater the keyboard lag when typing in those fields, but it starts rather quickly with around 10 rows (50 or so input fields). I thought it was related to some keyup event, but I disabled any and all on the page, issue persists. I've also tested this page in Firefox and Edge and they both have no issues, seems isolated to Chrome.

Are there any known causes for this behavior in Chrome, or is this more of an issue with the browser itself?

**Edit #1**
Adding in the complete code I used to replicate this issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#add').click(function(){
        var num = $('#num').val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        var numAdd = 1;
        if (num.length > 0) {
          var baseRow = $('#base');
          numAdd = parseInt(num);
          if (numAdd >= 1) {
            for (var i = 1; i <= numAdd; i++) {
              var newRow = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
              $(newRow).find('.bte').html('<span class="remove">remove</span>');
              $(newRow).find('.btn').html('');
              $(newRow).find('input').val('');
              $('#rows').append(newRow);
            }
          }
        }
      });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="list">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="btg">Field 1</th>
            <th class="btd">Field 2</th>
            <th class="btm">Field 3</th>
            <th class="btq">Field 4</th>
            <th class="btv">Field 5</th>
            <th class="bte"></th>
            <th class="btn"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="rows">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="text" value="1" readonly="readonly" style="width:60px;">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" value="" style="width:300px;">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" value="" style="width:60px;">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" value="" style="width:60px;">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" value="" style="width:60px;">
            </td>
            <td class="bte">
              <span id="add">add</span>
            </td>
            <td class="btn">
              <input type="text" id="num" value="" maxlength="2" placeholder="num rows to add">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

When adding in 35 rows, and start typing in one, I notice the lag, however it seems to be less severe, in some cases almost non-existent. If I have another Chrome window open with Play Music going, the issue becomes much more severe. The problem continues after that window is closed. Hard to know if related.

Also, if I just create this page with 35+ rows directly, not dynamic, never any keyboard lag.

Firefox still doesn't have this problem, even if I run multiple tabs and Play Music going.

This is a weird one. Maybe it is more related to my actual laptop setup than Chrome itself, or a combination of the two. I'm going to test this once I'm home on my desktop.

**Edit #2** 
Changed the jQuery to be pulled remotely, just to make this more portable and easier to use.

Comment: Do the inputs have any change event handlers on them?

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue? I'm not noticing any slowdown with 1000 rows with 5 inputs each ([codepen](http://codepen.io/FullR/pen/GjydWm))

Comment: No change events, and I even disabled all key events completely, still had the problem. The issue is still occurring, but I'll try to reproduce it in a completely new, bare-bones page.

Comment: Edited my post. If no one else has this problem I'm going to assume it's related more to the machine than software, or possible a combination of both.